# How can i call same xib in multiple views but distinguish which i'm interacting?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xib

I'm trying to use an xib file (which is just a simple view) on my viewcontroller more than once. I can add it on my viewcontroller more than once and interact with both of them. The question is, how can i distinguish between these views to know which one i'm clicking?

For example, when i tap on my firstview, i want to print "apples" and when i tap on second view i wan to print "oranges"

Below you can see my code and here is github repo for you to play with my code: https://github.com/TimurAykutYildirim/demoView/tree/multiple-instance

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Mini.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <SelectionProtocol>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet Mini *miniView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet Mini *miniView2;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.miniView.delegate = self;
    self.miniView2.delegate = self;
}


-(void) isClicked {
    NSLog(@"apples");
    NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

@end

**Mini.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SelectionProtocol;

@interface Mini : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SelectionProtocol> delegate;

- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender;

@end


@protocol SelectionProtocol <NSObject>

@required
-(void) isClicked;

@end
```

**Mini.m**

```
#import "Mini.h"

@implementation Mini

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self load];
    }

    return self;
}


- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self load];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)load {
    UIView *view = [[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] loadNibNamed:@"Mini" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
    [self addSubview:view];
    view.frame = self.bounds;


}
- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender {

    if ([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(SelectionProtocol)]) {
        [self.delegate isClicked];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: you can use different tag for each view. send the tag with protocol methods. i think it will be worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways that you could do that. Here are two:

1. Add a `sender` parameter to your `-[ViewController isClicked]` method, and change `Mini` so that calls to `-isClicked` pass in a pointer to `self`. Then the code in `-isClicked` can compare that to each of the instances of `Mini` that it knows about, i.e. `self.miniView` and `self.miniView2`, to see if either of those is the one that sent the message.
2. Add a property to `Mini` that lets you distinguish between the two, e.g. `name`. You can configure that property in `-viewDidLoad`, like `self.miniView.name = @"apples"`, or you can even do it in the .xib file using "user defined runtime attributes." Then you can have `Mini` pass it's `name` property as a parameter to methods that need to know which instance of `Mini` is the caller. (Or, combine 1 & 2 and pass a reference to `self` so that `ViewController` can examine the `name` parameter or anything else it wants.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming from your question that somewhere in the `Mini` xib there is an outlet with the text "apples" (or whichever fruit for that particular xib).

In that case, you can just change your protocol to:

```
- (void)isClickedFromView:(Mini *)mini
```

In the delegate (ViewController.m) change the `btnClick` action to:

```
- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender {
   if ([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(SelectionProtocol)]) {
     [self.delegate isClickedFromView:self];
   }
}
```

Add an outlet like `fruitLabel` to your `Mini` class.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fruitLabel
```

Now when the delegate gets the call you can call:

```
NSLog(@"Fruit: %@", mini.fruitLabel.text);
```

**===== Additional answer for if the data (in this case `fruits`) is available in code =====**

If you have the data programmatically already (like an array of fruits), It might be easier to just put the Mini classes in an array ordered the same way.

So if `miniViewArray` contains an array of your `Mini` classes,
and `fruitArray` contains an array of NSStrings of fruits you can do:

At the time you set the miniView's delegate you can add them to the array..something like:

```
NSArray *fruitArray = @[ @"apples", @"oranges" ];
NSArray *miniViewArray = @[ miniView, miniView2 ];
```

Then in the delegate call you can do (Using the same protocol change as above):

```
- (void)isClickedFromView:(Mini *)mini {
  NSInteger fruitIndex = [miniViewArray indexOfObject:mini];
  NSString fruitName = fruitArray[fruitIndex];
  NSLog(@"Fruit: %@", fruitName);
}
```

Comment: instead of adding another property, i set a tag for each view from attributes inspector. thanks though..

Comment: I updated the answer only because I think tagging each view in the xib isn't really scalable. If you are tagging the views in the xib, that means you have a reference in code for each tag. Please see my additional answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use `ENUM` for distinguish between the view type.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, <#MyViewType#>) {
    <#MyViewTypeDefault#>,
    <#MyViewTypeA#>,
    <#MyViewTypeB#>,
};

@property (nonatomic, assign) MyEnum viewType;
```

**Protocol:**

```
-(void) isClickedForViewType:(MyEnum)viewType;
```

Answer (score 0):

Common approach for calling delegate method is to include caller as a param. In your case it should be something like this:

```
 - (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender {
   if ([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(SelectionProtocol)]) {
     [self.delegate isClickedOnMiniView:self];
   }
 }
```

Basically, this convention was created to cover such cases - one object is a delegate of many similar ones.

Check apple docs for examples of this convention:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate